# bind click event after enabling the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code that I used to disable addnotice button & hence disable click event handler as well.

```
$( "#div_violation_template" ).on( "switchbuttonon",".switch-button-start-eviction", function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#div_violation_template .addNotice").addClass('disabled').off('click');
} );
```

Similarly, I enable the button addNotice link should get clickable and performed the desired thing but it removes only class and after clicking of addNotice button nothing happens.

```
$( "#div_violation_template" ).on( "switchbuttonoff",".switch-button-start-eviction", function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#div_violation_template .addNotice").removeClass('disabled').on('click');
} );
```

What is wrong in using on click event? I think it's similar to bind click event but not works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`.on('click')` doesn't do anything because you didn't define a callback function which will run when the button is clicked.

But why do you think you need to remove the click handler and then re-add it? If you make the button *actually* disabled using the disabled *property* (not just adding a CSS class to it) then the click event won't run anyway.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() { 
    $("#btn3").addClass("disabled").prop("disabled", true); 
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() { 
    $("#btn3").removeClass("disabled").prop("disabled", false); 
  });
  $("#btn3").click(function() { alert("Clicked Button 3") });
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1 - click to disable Button 3</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2 - click to enable Button 3</button>
<br/><br/>
<button id="btn3">Button 3 - click to see alert when enabled</button>
```

In your specific code it would be:

```
$( "#div_violation_template" ).on( "switchbuttonon",".switch-button-start-eviction", function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#div_violation_template .addNotice").addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
});

$( "#div_violation_template" ).on( "switchbuttonoff",".switch-button-start-eviction", function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#div_violation_template .addNotice").removeClass('disabled').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Something like this

```
$("#div_violation_template").on("switchbuttonoff",".switch-button-start-eviction", function( event, ui ) {
     $( "#div_violation_template .addNotice").on('click',function(e){
           $(this).removeClass('disabled');
     });
});
```

Comment: this produced different behaviour, but not what was requested. In the original code, setting the disabled class happens in the outer "switchbuttonoff" event, not in the click event.